# C# - Binary Search Tree Contains/Is Present Method

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree

I'm really struggling to get this method to work, I was wondering if you could help me out. I've been using the ref keyword, so I'll keep using it. I've been searching the web and it's been some help, but I've tried everything I can possibly think of. Both my count and height methods work, however, I'm just really struggling to get this Contain method to work. Many examples on the web have showed both  a public and private method of contains (I understand as to why) but I'm sure it could be done within one method? Surely, right? Also, please ignore the RemoveItem method, unless you wish to give me a head-start, that's at your discretion. I know it's tricky as I've looked up on it earlier during the week.

Node class-

```
    class Node<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private T data;
    public Node<T> Left, Right;

    public Node(T item)
    {
        data = item;
        Left = null;
        Right = null;
    }
    public T Data
    {
        set { data = value; }
        get { return data; }
    }

}
```

BinTree Class-

```
 class BinTree<T> where T : IComparable
{
    protected Node<T> root;

    public BinTree()  //creates an empty tree
    {
        root = null;
    }
    public BinTree(Node<T> node)  //creates a tree with node as the root
    {
        root = node;
    }
   //I've deleted my preOrder, inOrder and postOrder methods just to save you some time

}
```

BSTree Class-

```
 class BSTree<T> : BinTree<T> where T : IComparable
{  
    public BSTree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    private void insertItem(T item, ref Node<T> tree)
    {
        if (tree == null)
        {
            tree = new Node<T>(item);

        }

        else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) < 0)
        {
            insertItem(item, ref tree.Left);
        }

        else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) > 0)
            insertItem(item, ref tree.Right);
    }

    public void InsertItem(T item)
    {
        insertItem(item, ref root);
    }

    public int Height(ref Node<T> tree)
    //Return the max level of the tree
    {
        if (tree == null)

            return 0;
        return (1 + Math.Max(Height(ref tree.Left), Height(ref tree.Right)));
    }


    public int Count(ref Node<T> tree)
    //Return the number of nodes in the tree
    {
        int counter = 0;

        if (tree == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (tree.Left != null)
        {
            counter += Count(ref tree.Left);
            counter++;
        }

        if (tree.Right != null)
        {
            counter += Count(ref tree.Right);
            counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }



    public Boolean Contains(T item, ref Node<T> tree)
    //Return true if the item is contained in the BSTree, false       //otherwise.
    {
       if (tree == null)
        {
            return false;
        }



       if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) < 0)
        {
            return Contains(ref tree.Left);


            if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) > 0)
            {
                return Contains(ref tree.Right);
                return true;
            }
        }
  }

    public void RemoveItem(T item) 
    {
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is too much information.  Please boil this down to a [mcve], and define *specifically* what it is you'd like us to help you with.

Comment: Tree searches usually requires a recursive method or a push/pop method.

Comment: There are three possibilities for the result of `CompareTo: < 0 , > 0 or = 0`. You need to check all three to decide whether to stop the search successfully (on 0) or to search the left or right subtrees. At the moment your test for `item > tree root` is within the test for `item < tree root` which it should not be.

Comment: Is your code compiling? If it is, what behavior do you get?

Comment: your second if block  will never get called because its contained in an if block that precludes it from being true.

Comment: @rory.apI Apologise, I felt the classes I added were a critical component in term of understanding my code.

Comment: @KelsonBall Indeed it is, if I remove both the Contains and Remove method, complies and runs as expected.

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski Thank you for your insight and I will take that into account.

Answer (score 3):

To check if a node is in the tree, you have a few options:

1. The node you want is in the left sub-tree
2. The node you want is in the right sub-tree
3. The node you want is where you are right now

So your `Contains` method should look more like this:

```
public Boolean Contains(T item, ref Node<T> tree)
{
       if (tree == null)
       {
            return false;
       }

       if (tree.data == item)
       {
           return true;
       }  


       if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) < 0)
       {
            return Contains(item, ref tree.Left);
       }
       if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) > 0)
       {
            return Contains(item, ref tree.Right);
       }
  }
```

Comment: Item probably needs passed to the recursive calls. That's why I asked OP if his code was compiling :/

Comment: Good call @KelsonBall. I have edited the post to reflect these changes.

Comment: @KelsonBall Sorry for the late reply, I have answered your question.

Comment: @Libby Thank you for your answer, however, I have stumbled across an error "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'.

Comment: I upvoted but what's the point of the last `return false` and the second if statement? why not just add an else to the last if block?

Comment: The return false is if the item you are looking for is not in the tree. But now that I think about it, the first if statement should take care of that. The second if statement checks if the node you are currently looking at is the item that you are looking for

Comment: probably a good idea...plus there is the whole problem of using == with generic type.

Comment: Yes @LucasKot-Zaniewski, your solution is much cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool Contains(Node root, int value)
 {
    if(root == null)
        return false;
    if(root.Value == value)
        return true;
    if(value < root.Value)
        return Contains( root.Left,value);
    else
        return Contains( root.Right,value);
}
```

Comment: add description and say how you solution help to solve the problem :)