# C# : List item according to category in Binary Search Tree without using collection class

Tags: c#, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I need to make Binary Search Tree using following data. I cannot use collection class and application need to be console.
[image: Sample Data]

Binary Search will be sorted by toolName . I have to present below option for user.
[image: UI]

To my understanding for option 1: I can use probably use in-order traversal. I don't know how to list by type using BST. I am not sure if its even possible.
Can someone assist me with this issue.

Comment: This is not a site to do your homework for you. If you have a specific question, show  what inputs you have (as text, not images), what you expect as output, and most importantly what you have already tried.

Comment: As Jeremy mentioned, did you tried any solution yourself? If so, you can let us know where did you get stuck and we can help with that!

Comment: @YashGupta I think I need to learn to ask right question. Yes I am working on solution. I am able to insert data in BST, I am able to display all data using BST traversing. But I can't think of way to list only a certain item of particular category.  I am not good programmer I borrowed code from internet. Trying to join pieces of codes myself. I don't know how to share my codes here as it have 7 different class with 100s of line of code on them. I am really not asking for handout. Thanks

Comment: You need to search for the data which is of a specific "toolType" value and then display it. Here's an implementation of such method for BST that might assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40898855